# Ember.js Get key of changed value from .observes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

In [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), is there a way to get the key for an observed change within an object when observing multiple values with the same closure?

e.g.

```
MyItem = Ember.Object.extend
    name: null
    age: null
    height: null
    weight: null
    has_grown_or_shrunk: false
    has_grown_or_shrunk_obs: (->
        @set('has_grown_or_shrunk', true)
    ).observes('height','weight')
```

Is there any way for `has_grown_or_shrunk_obs` to know which of the keys triggered the change? It doesn't appear that there is from the docs [here](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Observable.html)

Is there another, better way of observing multiple keys with the same logic that will allow me to know which key changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is undocumented** as best as I can tell, but here is what I found

```
has_grown_or_shrunk_obs: (->
    console.log arguments
    @set('has_grown_or_shrunk', true)
).observes('height','weight')
```

Outputs:

```
[Class, "height", undefined]
```

Where "dom_class" is the name of my key. So it would appear that the second argument passed is the key of the changed element.

This pseudo code is how to get it done.

```
((self, key) ->
    #Logic here
).observes(key1, key2, key3...)
```